# How to go about having a button and a custom paint view on the same screen? android

Tags: java, android, listener, paint

I am pretty new to android and am trying to build an app where the user can draw a letter, press a button that connects a service that reads it, and then the letter is displayed  back to them.

This is my main layout:
!(http://i58.photobucket.com/albums/g271/billmoney3/layout_zps71eb45ca.jpg)

I want the user to be able to draw in the blue area. I made the blue area a custom view called InnerDrawingView. I need help on how to organize the views and the OnTouchListener.

Right now I have this java code:

```
public class DoodleActivity extends Activity {

Button confirmButton;
EditText drawingResult;
InnerDrawingView innerView;

// on create
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doodle);    // main layout

    // where the drawing happens
    innerView = (InnerDrawingView) findViewById(R.id.innerDrawingView1);
    innerView.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
            ...
            ...

// handle the touching of the inner view
private OnTouchListener handleTouch = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        drawingResult.setText("O RLY?!");       // just a test
        return true;
    }
}; // end of class
```

Is this the correct way to go about it? What kind of touch listener do I put in the InnerDrawingView class? Can I just call: innerView.onTouch() from inside my main activity's onTouch()? Or the onDraw() method? If someone could direct me to a good paint tutorial also that would help me a lot.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull x and y from the "event" object. Then the code depends on your needs. You can connect a new point with the previous one (to make a segment) or just put it in the list. Pseudo-code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    innerView.submitNewPoint(event.getX()), event.getY());
    return true;
}
```

If you want to handle multi-touch events you need to retrieve points count ( event.getPointerCount() ) and do something with coords from event.getX(i)/event.getY(i) (i - index of multi-touch event point).

Of cause you need to implement drawing of the points/segments/? list in the InnerDrawingView.

P.S. do not forget to make you fields private ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approach makes sense. This probly sounds trivial, but once I get the x and y coordinates, I paint them onto the view using onDraw correct? That's where drawing takes place I believe?

Comment: That's right. Actually there are several other ways to draw (OpenGL, for example), but for the beginning Canvas' methods are more than enough.